Query does not use index
I have this query:
Explain 
select SQL_NO_CACHE p.id as product_id, 
      p.price_amount, 
      p.is_male, 
      p.is_female, 
      p.is_accessories, 
      p.is_contact_lens, 
      c.id as color_id, 
      b.name as brand, 
      p.name, 
      c.color, 
      c.code, 
      c.pohoda_sku, 
      c.on_stock, 
      c.not_send_to_kiosks, 
      (p.is_active && !p.is_archive && c.is_active && !c.is_archive) as is_active, 
      c.is_visible, 
      c.abbr 
from product_colors as c 
left join products as p 
      on p.id = c.product_id 
left join brands as b 
      on p.brand_id = b.id 

order by c.on_stock desc


Why the query does not use index in first table? In phpmyadmin it durate 0.0708s, but on the web it is more than 1s. I do not want limit it by where or limit. Can I optimize this query or it is cause with some memory limit in php.ini or elsewhere?

Can you clarify a bit? It's the same query, running on a "web" or through "phpmyadmin", we are only comparing times? For me, as a resolution, or, a problem may be not on database side, but rather in web application logic. There may be cycles which run subsequent queries or multiple loops on same data, where phpmyadmin just displays the content in pretty effective way, as I know it. May this be the case?

This is a query that I need to run in the application. I'm just comparing times in phpmyadmin.

SQL_NO_CACHE are disables caching, potentially decreasing execution time.
try not using SQL_NO_CACHE.
also try increasing the memory_limit in php.ini configuration because the hosting server architecture is different from your local server

I use it just in phpmyadmin to test query. In production I do not use it.

MySQL can only use the index with
ORDER BY c.on_stock DESC
if it was created that way.
CREATE INDEX idx_desc_columns ON product_colors ( on_stock DESC);

try this:
select p.id as product_id, p.price_amount, p.is_male, p.is_female, p.is_accessories, p.is_contact_lens, c.id as color_id, b.name as brand, p.name, c.color, c.code, c.pohoda_sku, c.on_stock, c.not_send_to_kiosks, (p.is_active && !p.is_archive && c.is_active && !c.is_archive) as is_active, c.is_visible, c.abbr 
from ( SELECT * FROM product_colors order by on_stock desc) as c 
left join products as p on p.id = c.product_id 
left join brands as b on p.brand_id = b.id;

You can also change the * in the select to the fields you are using.
A other case
There are also other possibilities why the optimiter decides not to take an index. This is the case, for example, if the sort_buffer_size is configured too small.
You can query these like this
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sort_buffer_size';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_sort_buffer_size';

and then set it temporarily. When enlarging, make sure that there is enough memory available.
SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size = 4194304;  -- 4 MB or more
SET GLOBAL innodb_sort_buffer_size = 1048576;  -- 1 MB or more

If this is successful, you can also make these changes in my.ini as follows.
[mysqld]
sort_buffer_size = 4M
innodb_sort_buffer_size = 1M


Explain is same like before and query still durate over 1s..

@tomasr - i have add a other sample

there is not difference. In extra is not "file sort", but query durate the same time and does not use key.

@tomasr - i have add a other sample

sort_buffer_size: 8388608, innodb_sort_buffer_size: 1048576

@tomasr - Have you increased the values ​​once (e.g. doubled) to see whether the behavior improves
